# Java RegEx string within quotes but with additional requirement

Tags: java, regex

Hello this is my problem, and I would appreciate if you could help.

This is my regex: `\"(.*?)\"` and my goal is to collect each word etc. within `""`.

If i check it against `{$= "a=" "a" 0 @paramGet ", b=" "b" 0 @paramGet ", rezultat=" "a" 0
@paramGet "b" 0 @paramGet + $}` and collect all groups I get:

```
a=  a  , b=  b  ,rezultat=  a   b
```

but if check it against `{$= "a=" "a" 0 @paramGet ", b\"=" "b" 0 @paramGet ", rezu\"ltat=" "a" 0
@paramGet "b" 0 @paramGet + $}` I get:

```
"a="    "a"    ", b\"    " "     " 0 @paramGet "     "ltat="    "a"   "b"
```

This is my question: Is there any way to make regex recognize

```
a=  a  , b\"=  b  ,rezu\"ltat=  a   b
```

as whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. You can check that the character preceding the opening and closing double quotes is not a backslash:

   `[^\\]\"(.*?[^\\])\"`
2. Use a negative lookbehind regex:

   `(?<!\\)\"(.*?)(?<!\\)\"`

   where `(?<!b)a` means `a` not preceded with a `b`.

The latter seems to work better because it also matches empty strings as well.